# Concurrency/ToDo Sample not working

Tags: breeze

I was trying out the ToDo sample and ran into an unhandled Excaption while trying out the Concurrency Handling.

The dataservice.js contains these lines in `saveFailed(error)` method:

```
if (detail && detail.ExceptionType.indexOf('OptimisticConcurrencyException') !== -1) {
        // Concurrency error 
        reason =
            "Another user, perhaps the server, may have deleted one or all of the todos.";
        manager.rejectChanges(); // DEMO ONLY: discard all pending changes
    }
```

The client never gets to this point due to an unhandled OptimisticConcurrencyException in:

```
[HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
```

I was trying to catch this and return the Exception which was kind of stupid as the Exception is not of type `SaveResult`. Is this a bug or am i missing an configuration somewhere?

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any server side errors should be returned to the promise.fail handler. i.e.

```
em.saveChanges().then(function(saveResult) {
   // normal path

}).fail(function(error) {
   // your concurrency exception message will be part of the error object. 
});
```

Comment: That is what i want to do but i am not getting this far. In Debug Mode in Visual Studio the execution is halted and i get a windows with `Exception unhandled by User code`. On my test-server i get (Fiddler) `500 : {"$id":"1","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http","Message":"An error has occurred."}` No error Type. This might be a configuration error, i dont know (Windows Server 2012). I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: One problem persists. In debug on localhost i get the full JSON with ExceptionMessage, ExceptionType and StackTrace. Deploying the project as Release on the test-server gives me the JSON from my above comment when provoking ConcurrentException.

Answer (score 0):

Error on my side here... Clicking 'Continue' on the Exception Windows in VS the javascript handler is executed.